# Spring boot + Angular routing with parameter problem

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to write a simple UI service that's built upon Eureka Client, Ribbon Client, Spring Boot and Angular. I have a simple front in angular that has the following routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'course/:id', component: DetailedCourseComponent },
{ path: 'coursefix', component: DetailedCourseComponent }, // I did this one to test the parameter issue.

{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

And this specific course component:

DetailedCourseComponent.html

```
<p>detailed-course works!</p>
```

as you can see, I'm not too interested in the id parameter for the moment but I will use it eventually.

Whenever I test running the url for course/1 with angular on localhost through the CLI console (No spring boost, eureka, ribbon, etc) it works correctly showing the following message: "detailed-course works!"

Now whenever I compile the front into the "resources/static" folder with angular CLI and run the website from IntelijIdea it fails to access the url: "course/1" with an empty white screen. Although, if I enter the url /coursefix (Without any parameters) I get the "detailed-course works!" any idea of what can be causing this url parameter issue? I tried googling a lot but found no luck so far.

To clarify: Routing works correctly (When deployed with Spring boost), redirection also works once I enter the URL: http://localhost:9092/ => http://localhost:9092/home/

Just in case, this is my angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ui": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "./",
            "outputPath": "../../resources/static",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ui:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ui:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ui:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ui:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "ui"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When Angular is built, it creates a problem with URL and routing reference, you can only navigate if you access `localhost -> url1 -> url2`. If you try to go straight to `url2`, it doesn't work.

To answer this problem you need to add a `LocationHashStrategy` (that's how I managed to fix it). This adds a `#` in the URL, in case you don't like it, it doesn't help (i.e. `localhost/#/home`)

app-routing.module.ts:

```
...
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to the app.module

```
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

providers: [
    {
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: PathLocationStrategy
    }
]
```